# NoSuchMethodException on trying to get Nested bean property

Tags: java, nosuchmethoderror, apache-commons-beanutils

I have a Product class:

```
public class Product {

private ProductClass prodClass;

public ProductClass getProdClass() {
    return prodClass;
}

public void setProdClass(ProductClass prodClass) {
    this.prodClass = prodClass;
}
}
```

And another one ProductClass ...

```
public class ProductClass {

private String StbFlag;

public String getStbFlag() {
    return StbFlag;
}

public void setStbFlag(String stbFlag) {
    StbFlag = stbFlag;
}
}
```

When I try to get the Property using BeanUtils.getNestedProperty as shown below..

```
public class Test {

public static void main(String Args[]) {

    Product product = new Product();
    ProductClass proClass = new ProductClass();
    proClass.setStbFlag("abcd");
    product.setProdClass(proClass);

    try {
        String value = BeanUtils.getNestedProperty(product, "prodClass.StbFlag");
        System.out.println(value);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();  
    }
}
}
```

Its throwing the following exception...

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: Unknown property 'StbFlag' on class 'class ProductClass'
    at org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtilsBean.getSimpleProperty(PropertyUtilsBean.java:1313)
    at org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtilsBean.getNestedProperty(PropertyUtilsBean.java:762)
    at org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanUtilsBean.getNestedProperty(BeanUtilsBean.java:715)
    at org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanUtils.getNestedProperty(BeanUtils.java:354)
    at Test.main(Test.java:15)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:90)
```

What could be the reason? This is just a sample I used to find out the problem. I am actually mapping XML to Java Object and need to keep the name as StbFlag as per the xml tag.

It's working fine when I use STBflag or stbFlag as the variable name. Any workaround for this?

Comment: it give you `NoSuchMethodexception` try to write such thing `BeanUtils.getNestedProperty(product, "prodClass.getStbFlag");` may be this works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BeanUtils expects that your field names start with a lowercase letter, because it adheres to the JavaBean naming conventions.

In Section 8.8 of the [JavaBeans spec](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/spec-136004.html):

> Java programmers are accustomed to having normal identifiers start with
> lower case letters. Vigorous reviewer input has convinced us that we
> should follow this same conventional rule for property and event
> names.
>
> Thus when we extract a property or event name from the middle of an
> existing Java name, we normally convert the first character to lower
> case. However to support the occasional use of all upper-case names,
> we check if the first two characters of the name are both upper case
> and if so leave it alone. So for example, “FooBah” becomes “fooBah”
> “Z” becomes “z” “URL” becomes “URL”
>
> We provide a method Introspector.decapitalize which implements this conversion rule

That said, changing your code to this will fix it:

```
String value = BeanUtils.getNestedProperty(product, "prodClass.stbFlag");
```

If you are getting the string `"StbFlag"` from an XML file, I would recommend using the same `decapitalize` method that BeanUtils uses to convert it to the correct format.

```
Introspector.decapitalize("StbFlag")
```

which will return `"stbFlag"` as a result.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class ProductClass {

private String StbFlag;

public String getStbFlag() {
    return StbFlag;
}

public void setStbFlag(String stbFlag) {
    this.StbFlag = stbFlag;//error here write this get anwser
}
}
```

write this code anwser is coming

Comment: this is exactly the same code the OP posted, what is this supposed to demonstrate?